# Генерация координат в окрестности

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим, что у меня есть поле `NxN`, с координатами `0, 1, 2, ..., N-1` по первой оси и `0, 1, 2, ..., N-1` по второй оси. Каким образом можно записать функцию, которая генерирует всевозможные кортежи из `k` координат, такие что для любых двух координат в этом кортеже их горизонтальное и вертикальное расстояние (по сути по одной и другой оси) не превышает 1? Координаты  в кортеже не должны повторяться.

Пример для поля `2x2` и `k=1`, будет `[(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]`,

для `k=2` будет `[((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 0), (1, 0)), ((0, 0), (1, 1)), ((0, 1), (1, 0)), ((0, 1), (1, 1)), ((1, 0), (1, 1))]`.

Comment: можно пример для `n = 3, k = 1`?

Comment: Это будут все одиночные координаты, `(i,j), i,j  e [0,1,2]`, т.к. всего одна координата, попарное расстояние 0)